# DPDK nes: Qemu due to missing usvhost-1 char device

Tags: dpdk

In the process of Configuring NES environment for mobile edge computing using DPDK, system is generating an error message as follows:

> Qemu-System-X86_64: -Chardev Socket,Id=Char1,Path=/Usr/Bin/Usvhost-1:
>   Failed To Connect Socket: No Such File Or Directory

Note: I am using CentOS 7.

List of commands used as follows:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/huge-1048576kB
mount -t hugetlbfs nodev /mnt/huge-1048576kB

./scripts/setup.sh

nginx
redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf &

tunctl -t tap0
brctl addif virbr0 tap0
ifconfig eno1 0 up
ip addr add 10.138.77.17/24 dev virbr0

export RTE_SDK=/opt/dpdk-stable-16.07.2
export RTE_TARGET=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc
make

export NES_SERVER_CONF=/opt/intel/nev_sdk/nes_root/scripts/nes.cfg

cd scripts/
./nes-daemon-start 
0000:1c:00.1 already bound to driver igb_uio, skipping
0000:1c:00.0 already bound to driver igb_uio, skipping


/usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -cpu host -m 4096 -no-reboot -no-hpet -drive file=/home/tcs/ubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso,if=virtio,id=drive-virtio-disk1,format=raw -object memory-backend-file,id=mem,size=4096M,mem-path=/mnt/huge-1048576kB/,share=on -numa node,memdev=mem -mem-prealloc -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0,mac=ac:1f:6b:09:cb:9a -netdev type=tap,id=net0 -chardev socket,id=char1,path=/usr/bin/usvhost-1 -netdev type=vhost-user,id=mynet1,chardev=char1 -device virtio-net-pci,mac=52:54:00:00:00:01,netdev=mynet1,id=net1,csum=off,gso=off,guest_csum=off,guest_tso4=off,guest_tso6=off,guest_ecn=off
Qemu-System-X86_64: -Chardev Socket,Id=Char1,Path=/Usr/Bin/Usvhost-1: Failed To Connect Socket: No Such File Or Directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with NES, but from the listed commands it looks like after `./nes-daemon-start` there should be a Unix socket in `/Usr/Bin/Usvhost-1`.

Since QEMU fails to connect to socket `/Usr/Bin/Usvhost-1`, apparently `nes-daemon-start` creates socket in another place.

The solution would be to check if the path `/Usr/Bin/Usvhost-1` is correct. On most Unix file systems there is a differentiation in letter case, i.e. `/Usr` and `/usr` are different paths. So maybe this is the case QEMU cannot find the provided path.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
The path mentioned /Usr/Bin/Usvhost-1 (Typo error ) is actually /usr/bin/usvhost-1.
The file usvhost-1 has not been created. So this error is coming.
In fact, I create this as character device in same path. There is error in opening this file.
Any suggestion?

Comment: It is not a file, it should be a socket created by `nes-daemon-start`.  There is no need to create it manually, just check where `nes-daemon-start` is creating it and change the path in QEMU arguments accordingly.

Comment: Right, nes-daemon-start using nes.cfg, where I have defined for PORT0:
[PORT0]
name = ENB
pci-address = 0000:1c:00.0
traffic-type = LTE
traffic-direction = upstream
egress-port = 1
ip-addresses = 10.138.77.32:1,10.138.77.10:1
mac = ac:1f:6b:09:cb:9a

#./nes-daemon-start 
SW Only platform detected
Routing table indicates that interface 0000:1c:00.0 is active. Not modifying

/var/log/nes.log
ES: [ERR] Unable to find port id for pci_addr=0000:1c:00.0
NES: [EMERG] nes_dev_port_new_device initialization failed!NES: [ERR] Could not initialize interfaces.

Comment: so usvhost-1 socket file not created.

It there anything wrong in nes.cfg file for PORT0 configuration as mentioned above. Please help on this.

Comment: @sanjay I am not familiar with NES, sorry :(